# How to call a function within another function when they both have different number of parameters?

Tags: python, function, recursion, quicksort, self

I have written this function:

```
def sort2(self, start, end):
    if (start == None or start == end or start == end.next):
        return

    # split list and partition recurse
    pivot_prev = self.paritionLast(start, end)
    self.sort(start, pivot_prev)

    if (pivot_prev != None and pivot_prev == start):
        self.sort(pivot_prev.next, end)

    # if pivot is in between of the list,start from next of pivot,
    # since we have pivot_prev, so we move two nodes
    elif (pivot_prev != None and pivot_prev.next != None):
        self.sort(pivot_prev.next.next, end)
```

But my assignment requires it to be a function called `sort(self)`. How is that possible? I don't know how to write this program without all three parameters, so I thought I would just make a function `sort(self)` and call `sort2()` under it, is that possible?

Comment: Provide default values for the second and third parameter. Or make the second function a local function inside the outer function (is possible in Python)

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly define that function as a local function inside the method that has the signature that is needed. The local function will then not take a `self` parameter:

```
def sort(self):

    def sort2(start, end):
        if (start == None or start == end or start == end.next):
            return
    
        # split list and partition recurse
        pivot_prev = self.paritionLast(start, end)
        sort2(start, pivot_prev)
    
        if (pivot_prev != None and pivot_prev == start):
            sort2(pivot_prev.next, end)
    
        # if pivot is in between of the list,start from next of pivot,
        # since we have pivot_prev, so we move two nodes
        elif (pivot_prev != None and pivot_prev.next != None):
            self2(pivot_prev.next.next, end)

    # make the nested call
    sort2(self.head, self.tail)
```

Unrelated, but there is a thing happening in your code that is suspicious. When the first recursive call is made, the node `pivot_prev` might be swapped to a different location, which is a problem, because the second recursive call assumes the rightside partition starts at `pivot_prev.next`. This will generally not lead to a wrong sort order, but will affect the running time.

You should better *first* get a reference to `pivot_prev.next` (in a different local name), and only then make the first recursive call.